# How to parse this xml file?

Tags: java, xml, ksoap2, kxml2

I am making a quiz game with content in a xml files. I used java language

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<LQuiz>
    <Topic id="1" name="About Sun" time="900">
        <question
            name="1. The radiations emitted by the sun and responsible for the cause of skin cancer are...">
            <answer correctness="true">ultra-violet</answer>
            <answer correctness="false">infra-red</answer>
            <answer correctness="false">X-rays</answer>
            <answer correctness="false">micro waves</answer>
            <advice>One of two first</advice>
        </question>
        <question name="2. The source of energy of the sun is...">
            <answer correctness="false">nuclear fission</answer>
            <answer correctness="false">chemical reaction</answer>
            <answer correctness="true">nuclear fusion</answer>
            <answer correctness="false">photoelectric effect</answer>
            <advice>no prompt</advice>
        </question>     
    </Topic>
    <Topic id="2" name="Natural Resources" time="600">
        <question name="1. What are some examples of Non-Renewable Resources?">
            <answer correctness="true">Coal</answer>
            <answer correctness="true">Oil</answer>
            <answer correctness="false">Biomass</answer>
            <advice>no prompt</advice>
        </question>
        <question name="2. What are some alternative sources of energy?">
            <answer correctness="true">Wind</answer>
            <answer correctness="true">Hydro</answer>
            <answer correctness="false">Natural gas</answer>
            <answer correctness="true">Fusion</answer>
            <advice>Select correct variants</advice>
        </question>
         </Topic>
</LQuiz>
```

Can anybody help me how to parse this xml file using kxmls or ksoaps ? Sorry if this is a bad question. I need a example code please.

Comment: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152  use google. Took me 3 seconds :)

Answer (score 0):

The wiki for the ksoap2-android project has [a number of links](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/Links) that explain it all to you. If you have detailed questions ask another question here or on the project mailing list.